# Расширенная электронная торговля Google Analytics - отправка данных о показе товара

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-analytics

Ситуация следующая. На главной странице есть скрипт, который выводит товары. В данный момент у нас 33 товара.

В цикле вывода товаров, я установил след. код:

```
 while()
    {
      выводим товар

       ga("ec:addImpression", {
              "id": "'.$sale['id'].'",
              "name": "'.str_replace(array("'", "\"", "&quot;", "«", "»"), "'", htmlspecialchars(mb_substr($sale['titleshort'], 0, 64, 'utf-8')) ).'",
              "price": "'.$minprice.'",
              "brand": "'.get_string_between($data_partner['name'], '"', '"').'",
              "category": "'.$url['name'].' / '.$subct['name'].'",
              "position": "'.++$i.'",
              "list": "Главная страница",
            });

ga("send", "event", "catalog", "impression", {"nonInteraction": true}, {
              hitCallback: function() {
              }
            });
    }
```

как вы видите, после каждого addImpression я сразу отсылаю ивентом инфо в ГА. Однако в режиме реального времени я вижу, что отрабатывается только первые 19 событий, тоесть успевает отправиться информация о показе только первых 19 товаров из цикла, а у меня их 33. Я уже выставлял

```
hitCallback: function() {
              }
```

что бы заставить отработать каждый запрос, но всеравно пока товары выгружаются не все. Может кто то подскажет как это можно попробовать реализовать еще?

Comment: В генерируем коде у вас 33 вызова `ga("ec:addImpression"` или 19? Нет ли ошибок в консоли?

Comment: С вопросом уже разобрался самостоятельно. ГА скрипт говорит что слишком часто делаю запросы и после 19 запроса начинает игнорировать. В этом и ошибка. Пробую создать массивы данных не более чем по 8 кб и тогда отправлять в несколько запросов. Это и будет решением для любого рода выгрузки данных в ГА

Comment: просто ga("send", "event", "catalog" надо как то 1 раз отправлять

Comment: попробуйте вызывать `ga("ec:addImpression"...` ,а когда всё вывелось  `ga("send",..` Просто возможен вариант что последний Impression отправится

Comment: В одном запросе не получится отправить все товары. Сейчас к примеру 30 товаров потом будет 100. На запрос выделяется всего 8 кб, В любом случае рано или поздно придется дробить отправку.

Comment: @iSeeDev Я правильно понимаю, что гугл аналитика обрубает запрос более 8кб? Или такой размер используется чисто для подстраховки? Есть какие-нибудь ссылки на документацию или какие-то другие сторонние источники, в которых про это пишут?